# Extra verbose output from mdtool?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a project in Xamarin.iOS, and it happens to go through a build server (running on a Mac).

The build seems to commonly fail, but even with the `--verbose` or `-v` it seems to Silently fail. For example, right now, it seems to fail after optimizing the graphics for iOS. The last line of the build says `Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings`. But then I get a `Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure` from Jenkins. I know that this is a failure in the mdtool build, because I have had a successful build before, and I know there are several more steps before it actually succeeds.

The next step in the successful process should be `Compiling to native code`, but for some reason it fails before getting to that, or at least outputting it to the console.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few places in the mdtool build logic that didn't properly catch exceptions when executing shell programs which I (hopefully) fixed for Xamarin Studio 4.0.2.

Without seeing the full build log it's hard to say for sure, but it might be that whatever shell command that it is trying to execute either doesn't exist or isn't marked with execute permissions.

The programs that I can think of off the top of my head that mdtool will invoke for the iOS builds are:

1. `pngcrush` (optimizes .png files)
2. `plutil` (optimizes .plist and .strings files)
3. `codesign` (although this one gets called *after* compiling to native code)

and of course, `mtouch` which is what is used to compile IL to native code. The `mtouch` command is part of Xamarin.iOS while the other 3 utilities are part of Mac OS X (or Xcode).

The solution for the other person with a similar problem that I helped debug a week or 2 ago was because he had modified his PATH environment that `launchd` launched apps with to not include /usr/bin and so mdtool couldn't find the utility programs listed above.

I'm not very familiar with Jenkins (I know we use it at Xamarin, but I'm not part of the team that does), so make sure that the PATH environment that it launches mdtool under is setup to include /usr/bin.

Hope that helps.